# Составной диапазон из разных ячеек EXCEL (C#)

Tags: c#, excel

Для ограничения доступа к ячейкам EXCEL через C# применяю метод `Worksheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add(NameRange, range);`
Проблема возникает при попытке внести защиту на составной диапазон из разных ячеек одной строки. В VBA это делалось так -

```
    ActiveSheet.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="Имя", Range:=Range _
    ("R9,T9,W9:W10")
```

Не как не возьму в толк как в переменную range впихнуть такой диапазон. Пример ниже не работает -

```
Range range = Worksheet.Range["R9,T9,W9:W10"];
```

Comment: `R9,T9,W9:W10` - это в экселе как выглядит?

Comment: В экселе это несколько ячеек с текстовыми данными расположенными на одной строке.

Comment: Нашёл на одном из ресурсов вот такой подход -         xlRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A7:A9,A12,A14", misValue);       Но при попытке прикрутить это бьёт исключение - -  $exception {"Исключение из HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"} System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException

Comment: Ссылка - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363163/fastest-way-to-get-an-excel-range-of-rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По видимому я не учёл региональные настройки при реализации программы.
Всего то надо не запятую а ; ставить -

```
xlRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A7:A9;A12;A14", misValue);
```

[Ссылка на решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12363163/fastest-way-to-get-an-excel-range-of-rows)